# Warning--I didn't find a database entry for ":"

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

This warning is somewhat different than the other questions I've seen on this site, in that only a colon and now bibtexkey is mentioned. It doesn't cause an error and seem output seems fine to me, but I'm interested in what I would need to clean up to make get rid of this warning.

I use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.

When I run BibTex, I get `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for ":"` after the usual output. I've checked by searching for `{:}` in my document to make sure I am never citing anything by this bibtexkey, like `\cite[...]{:}` or `\cite[...]{:}` and did not find anything. But that would also cause undefined citations, I believe, because it would certainly be a typo.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Look in the `.aux` file whether you find `\citation{:}`

Comment: there is no `\citation{...}` of any kind, but lots of `\bibcite{...}`'s though. No `\bibcite{:}`, however

Comment: Hmmm, BibTeX only searches for those entries for which it can find a `\citation{<entry key>}` in the `.aux` file (unless an entry is referenced in a `crossref` field of another entry for which there is a  `\citation`; `\citation{*}` automatically applies to all available entries). If there are no `\citation`s at all, BibTeX shouldn't even try to look for citations, indeed it should complain `I found no \citation commands`. ... So I guess what I'm trying to say is: please try to throw together a small example document that reproduces the message.

Comment: thanks for your help, but, by accident, I found a typo that I had made and corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the answer by accident:
I had mistyped `\citep[...]:`, using square brackets instead of curled ones.
After making some other changes and recompiling I noticed that there were undefined citations. To me, it seems like this message wasn't there before, but I don't know if that's plausible, so probably I had just missed it.

Answer (score 2):

If I try with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{x}

\citep[x]:

\end{document}
```

then the `.aux` file contains

```
\relax
\citation{x}
\citation{:}
```

These entries will be picked up by BibTeX in order to populate the `.bbl` file. Once you run BibTeX and LaTeX again, the entries in the `.bbl` file will produce `\bibcite` lines in the `.aux` file, such as

```
\bibcite{x}{{1}{2020}{{Uthor}}{{}}}
```

Thus you will be able to find the offending `\citation{:}` entry in the `.aux` file and guess where the problem is. A binary search can be useful to narrow down the lookup.

The warning

```
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for “:”
```

can *only* be issued by BibTeX and it only looks for `\citation` lines in the `.aux` file. So if the warning is issued, there *is* a line of the form `\citation{:}`.